# Why use wp_send_json() over echo json_encode()?

Tags: ajax, json

When sending a JSON response back to an AJAX request, why use the WordPress function `wp_send_json()` and not `echo json_encode()`? What is the benefit of using the WordPress function `wp_send_json()` over `echo json_encode()`?

Ref: [`wp_send_json`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_send_json)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`wp_send_json()` handles all parts of returning content in an AJAX call. First off, it sets the content type of the returned content to `application/json` with the proper charset. Secondly, it automatically calls `wp_die()` after sending the JSON result, which is necessary in an AJAX call in WordPress.

You could consider using `wp_send_json_success()` for successful requests and `wp_send_json_error()` for erroneous requests, thereby adhering to the WordPress standards for handling AJAX requests. These functions set a `success` (boolean) and `data` (any type) key in an array and encode that entire array, thereby allowing you easily check in a structured way whether the request was successful or whether something went wrong.