# Best way to end WordPress ajax request and why?

Tags: ajax

Considering regular WordPress ajax requests like these:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_merrychristmas_happynewyear', array( $this, 'merrychristmas_happynewyear' ) );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_merrychristmas_happynewyear', array( $this, 'merrychristmas_happynewyear' ) );
```

Will it be best to end function `merrychristmas_happynewyear` with `die()`, `die(0)`, `wp_die()`, or something else and why?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Using `wp_die()` is the best of those options.

As others have noted, there are many reasons to prefer a WordPress-specific function over the plain `die` or `exit`:

- It allows other plugins to hook into the actions called by `wp_die()`.
- It allows a special handler for exiting to be used based on context (the behavior of `wp_die()` is tailored based on whether the request is an Ajax request or not).
- It makes it possible to test your code.

The last one is more important, which is why [I added that note to the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/index.php?title=AJAX_in_Plugins&diff=148870&oldid=148219). If you want to [create unit/integration tests](http://codesymphony.co/wp-ajax-plugin-unit-testing/) for your code, you will not be able to test a function that calls `exit` or `die` directly. It will terminate the script, like it is supposed to. The way that WordPress's own tests are set up to avoid this (for the Ajax callbacks that it has tests for), is to hook into the actions triggered by `wp_die()` and throw an exception. This allows the exception to be caught within the test, and the output of the callback (if any) to be analyzed.

The only time that you would use `die` or `exit` is if you want to bypass any special handling from `wp_die()` and kill the execution immediately. There are some places where WordPress does this (and other places where it might use `die` directly just because the handling from `wp_die()` is not important, or nobody has attempted to create tests for a piece of code yet, so it was overlooked). Remember that this also makes your code more difficult to test, so it would generally only be used in code that isn't in a function body anyway (like WordPress does in `admin-ajax.php`). So if the handling from `wp_die()` is specifically not desired, or you are killing the script at a certain point as a precaution (like `admin-ajax.php` does, expecting that usually an Ajax callback will have already properly exited), then you might consider using `die` directly.

In terms of `wp_die()` vs `wp_die( 0 )`, which you should use depends on what is handling the response of that Ajax request on the front end. If it is expecting a particular response body, then you need to pass that message (or integer, in this case) to `wp_die()`. If all it is listening for is the response being successful (`200` response code or whatever), then there is no need to pass anything to `wp_die()`. I would note, though, that ending with `wp_die( 0 )` would make the response indistinguishable from the default `admin-ajax.php` response. So ending with `0` does not tell you whether your callback was hooked up properly and actually ran. A different message would be better.

As pointed out in other answers, you will often find `wp_send_json()` et al. to be helpful if you are sending a JSON response back, which is generally a good idea. This is also superior to just calling `wp_die()` with a code, because you can pass much more information back in a JSON object, if needed. Using `wp_send_json_success()` and `wp_send_json_error()` will also send the success/error message back in a standard format that any JS Ajax helper functions provided by WordPress will be able to understand (like [`wp.ajax`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/js/wp-util.js?rev=37851#L99)).

**TL;DR:** You should probably always use `wp_die()`, whether in an Ajax callback or not. Even better, send information back with `wp_send_json()` and friends.

Comment: You added some good points of view. I updated the thread with my thoughts. You may comment if you like. @J.D

Comment: @prosti Thanks, I've added a paragraph on when and why you/WordPress might use `die` instead of `wp_die()`.

Comment: I appreciate your effort, however, I don't understand why WordPress core sometimes used `die()` and sometimes `wp_die()`.

Comment: Thanks @prosti. As for why WordPress sometimes uses `die()`, in some cases it is just legacy code, or `die()` is being used to kill the script as a last resort when something really unexpected happened and `wp_die()` didn't get called. In other cases, nobody has created tests for a piece of code, and the special handling from `wp_die()` isn't specifically needed, so it's been overlooked.

Answer (score 14):

From the codex [**AJAX in Plugins**](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );

function my_action_callback() {
    global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database

    $whatever = intval( $_POST['whatever'] );

    $whatever += 10;

        echo $whatever;

    wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
}
```

> Notice the use of `wp_die()`, instead of `die()` or `exit()`. Most of the
>   time you should be using `wp_die()` in your Ajax callback function. This
>   provides better integration with WordPress and makes it easier to test
>   your code.

Comment: the ccodex you noted is great, but WordPress core doesn't follow it. How about that?

Comment: All the `wp_send_json_*` functions all use `wp_send_json` which still calls `wp_die`

Comment: But why, I am missing something in here. Have you analyzed these functions and came up with the conclusions?

Comment: do you mind to add the note about `wp_send_json` into the answer?

Comment: which is correct? wp_die(0) or wp_die()?

Answer (score 10):

You can also use [`wp_send_json()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_send_json) described in the Codex as `send a JSON response back to an AJAX request, and die().`

So, if you have to return an array, you only have end your function with `wp_send_json($array_with_values);`. No need to `echo` or `die`.

You also get two help helper functions [`wp_send_json_success()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_send_json_success) and [`wp_send_json_error()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_send_json_error) which adds a key named `success` which will be `true` or `false` respectively.

For example:

```
$array_val = range( 1,10 );
var_dump( wp_send_json_error( $array_val ) ); # Output: {"success":false,"data":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]}
echo 'Hey there'; # Not executed because already died.
```

Comment: `wp_json_encode` in case of an exception may return false, what in that case?

Comment: It throws an exception if the third argument (depth) is less than 0.

Comment: So you believe the `wp_send_json()` is the best way? Why?

Comment: @prosti `wp_send_json()` [does some stuff](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-includes/functions.php#L3034) for us. [This question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/149158/why-use-wp-send-json-over-echo-json-encode) also deals with `wp_send_json()`.

Comment: This is exactly @RRikesh why I am asking the WP core uses that function. So why this? Is it better that way?

Comment: Less code while keeping things concise. I find it better.

Answer (score 3):

For using wordpress ajax / woo commerce ajax general syntax is as follows:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
function my_action_callback()
{
// your code goes here

wp_die();

}
```

You should use wp_die() at end of the function.Because wordpress internally uses a **filter** during wp_die() function.So any plugin which is working using that filter may not work if we do not include the wp_die(). Also die() and other functions are immediately kill the PHP execution without considering any wordpress function which should be consider while terminating execution.

If you are using wp_send_json() inside you function like this

```
       function my_action_callback()
    {
    // your code goes here

      wp_send_json();

    //wp_die(); not necessary to use wp_die();

    }
```

**Its not necessary to use wp_die() at the end if you include wp_send_json() inside callback function**. because wordpress itself use wp_die() function safely inside wp_send_json() function.

Answer (score 2):

This is just in addition to what others said. The reason to prefer `wp_die` is that core can trigger actions there and plugins can properly complete things like tracing, monitoring, or caching.

In general you should always prefer a core API call over if one available as it is most likely adding some value (caching, plugin integration or whatever) which you don't get from the direct PHP call.

Answer (score 2):

I will not accept this answer, this would not be fair. I just wanted to create an outline and possible hints on the items I find important:

#### The main definition of wp-die()

```
File: wp-includes/functions.php
2607: /**
2608:  * Kill WordPress execution and display HTML message with error message.
2609:  *
2610:  * This function complements the `die()` PHP function. The difference is that
2611:  * HTML will be displayed to the user. It is recommended to use this function
2612:  * only when the execution should not continue any further. It is not recommended
2613:  * to call this function very often, and try to handle as many errors as possible
2614:  * silently or more gracefully.
2615:  *
2616:  * As a shorthand, the desired HTTP response code may be passed as an integer to
2617:  * the `$title` parameter (the default title would apply) or the `$args` parameter.
2618:  *
2619:  * @since 2.0.4
2620:  * @since 4.1.0 The `$title` and `$args` parameters were changed to optionally accept
2621:  *              an integer to be used as the response code.
2622:  *
2623:  * @param string|WP_Error  $message Optional. Error message. If this is a WP_Error object,
2624:  *                                  and not an Ajax or XML-RPC request, the error's messages are used.
2625:  *                                  Default empty.
2626:  * @param string|int       $title   Optional. Error title. If `$message` is a `WP_Error` object,
2627:  *                                  error data with the key 'title' may be used to specify the title.
2628:  *                                  If `$title` is an integer, then it is treated as the response
2629:  *                                  code. Default empty.
2630:  * @param string|array|int $args {
2631:  *     Optional. Arguments to control behavior. If `$args` is an integer, then it is treated
2632:  *     as the response code. Default empty array.
2633:  *
2634:  *     @type int    $response       The HTTP response code. Default 200 for Ajax requests, 500 otherwise.
2635:  *     @type bool   $back_link      Whether to include a link to go back. Default false.
2636:  *     @type string $text_direction The text direction. This is only useful internally, when WordPress
2637:  *                                  is still loading and the site's locale is not set up yet. Accepts 'rtl'.
2638:  *                                  Default is the value of is_rtl().
2639:  * }
2640:  */
2641: function wp_die( $message = '', $title = '', $args = array() ) {
2642: 
2643:   if ( is_int( $args ) ) {
2644:       $args = array( 'response' => $args );
2645:   } elseif ( is_int( $title ) ) {
2646:       $args  = array( 'response' => $title );
2647:       $title = '';
2648:   }
2649: 
2650:   if ( wp_doing_ajax() ) {
2651:       /**
2652:        * Filters the callback for killing WordPress execution for Ajax requests.
2653:        *
2654:        * @since 3.4.0
2655:        *
2656:        * @param callable $function Callback function name.
2657:        */
2658:       $function = apply_filters( 'wp_die_ajax_handler', '_ajax_wp_die_handler' );
2659:   } elseif ( defined( 'XMLRPC_REQUEST' ) && XMLRPC_REQUEST ) {
2660:       /**
2661:        * Filters the callback for killing WordPress execution for XML-RPC requests.
2662:        *
2663:        * @since 3.4.0
2664:        *
2665:        * @param callable $function Callback function name.
2666:        */
2667:       $function = apply_filters( 'wp_die_xmlrpc_handler', '_xmlrpc_wp_die_handler' );
2668:   } else {
2669:       /**
2670:        * Filters the callback for killing WordPress execution for all non-Ajax, non-XML-RPC requests.
2671:        *
2672:        * @since 3.0.0
2673:        *
2674:        * @param callable $function Callback function name.
2675:        */
2676:       $function = apply_filters( 'wp_die_handler', '_default_wp_die_handler' );
2677:   }
2678: 
2679:   call_user_func( $function, $message, $title, $args );
2680: }
```

#### wp_send_json

```
File: wp-includes/functions.php
3144: /**
3145:  * Send a JSON response back to an Ajax request.
3146:  *
3147:  * @since 3.5.0
3148:  * @since 4.7.0 The `$status_code` parameter was added.
3149:  *
3150:  * @param mixed $response    Variable (usually an array or object) to encode as JSON,
3151:  *                           then print and die.
3152:  * @param int   $status_code The HTTP status code to output.
3153:  */
3154: function wp_send_json( $response, $status_code = null ) {
3155:   @header( 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=' . get_option( 'blog_charset' ) );
3156:   if ( null !== $status_code ) {
3157:       status_header( $status_code );
3158:   }
3159:   echo wp_json_encode( $response );
3160: 
3161:   if ( wp_doing_ajax() ) {
3162:       wp_die( '', '', array(
3163:           'response' => null,
3164:       ) );
3165:   } else {
3166:       die;
3167:   }
3168: }
```

#### wp_doing_ajax

```
File: wp-includes/load.php
1044: /**
1045:  * Determines whether the current request is a WordPress Ajax request.
1046:  *
1047:  * @since 4.7.0
1048:  *
1049:  * @return bool True if it's a WordPress Ajax request, false otherwise.
1050:  */
1051: function wp_doing_ajax() {
1052:   /**
1053:    * Filters whether the current request is a WordPress Ajax request.
1054:    *
1055:    * @since 4.7.0
1056:    *
1057:    * @param bool $wp_doing_ajax Whether the current request is a WordPress Ajax request.
1058:    */
1059:   return apply_filters( 'wp_doing_ajax', defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX );
1060: }
```

---

Typically what we get from ajax call is some kind of the response.
The response may be encoded in json or may not be encoded in json.

In case we need `json` outupt `wp_send_json` or two satelites are great idea.

However, we may return `x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` or `text/xml` or any other encoding type. In that case we don't use `wp_send_json`.

We may return the whole html and in that case it has sense to use `wp_die()` first and second parameter, else these parameters should be empty.

```
 wp_die( '', '', array(
      'response' => null,
 ) );
```

But what is a benefit of calling `wp_die()` without parameters?

---

Finaly, if you check the great WP core you may find

```
File: wp-includes/class-wp-ajax-response.php
139:    /**
140:     * Display XML formatted responses.
141:     *
142:     * Sets the content type header to text/xml.
143:     *
144:     * @since 2.1.0
145:     */
146:    public function send() {
147:        header( 'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=' . get_option( 'blog_charset' ) );
148:        echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='" . get_option( 'blog_charset' ) . "' standalone='yes'?><wp_ajax>";
149:        foreach ( (array) $this->responses as $response )
150:            echo $response;
151:        echo '</wp_ajax>';
152:        if ( wp_doing_ajax() )
153:            wp_die();
154:        else
155:            die();
```

Both formats are used `die()` and `wp_die()`. Can you explain why?

Finally here is what `admin-ajax.php` returns `die( '0' );`

Why not `wp_die(...)`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `wp_die()`. It is better to use WordPress functions as much as you can.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `echo`, it will force you to use `die()` or `die(0)` or `wp_die()`.

If you don’t use `echo`, JavaScript can handle that.

Then you should use a better way to return data: `wp_send_json()`.

To send data in your callback (in `json` format), you can use followings:

`wp_send_json()`

`wp_send_json_success()`

`wp_send_json_error()`

All of them will die for you. No need to exit or die afterwards.

**UPDATE**

And if you don't need `json` as output format, you should use:

`wp_die($response)`

It will return your response before it dies. As per the codex:

> The function `wp_die()` is designed to give output just before it dies
>   to avoid empty or time-outing responses.

Please read full codex article [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_die).

Comment: Thanks, what do you suggest instead of `echo`?

Comment: To note, Javascript doesn't handle `echo`. `wp_send_json_*` uses `echo` and exits for you. There is confusion here between the client and server.

Comment: @prosti wp_send_json()

Comment: Thanks, and in case we don't need `json` as output format?

Comment: @prosti than you should use wp_die($response) because as per the codex: The function wp_die() is designed to give output just before it dies to avoid empty or time-outing responses.

Comment: Thanks, @FaisalAlvi please [edit] your answer to make it appealing for upvotes then. Don't leave important details in the comments.

Comment: @prosti Thank you. Just updated the [answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/255822/73262).